# What is causing my Wavefront Obj parser to consume 10x more memory than the input?

Tags: performance, parsing, haskell, memory-leaks

I'm trying to write a parser for the [Wavefront `.obj` file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file), which is a really dumb line based format. Hopefully that wikipedia article should summarise how it works, but essentially you have lines that record entries in vertex, normal and other arrays. Finally, a face definition is a triple (or more) of indices into these separate arrays.

My parser is

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module WavefrontObj where

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Attoparsec.Text
import Data.Foldable (toList)
import Data.List (foldl')
import Data.List.Split
import Data.Monoid
import Data.NonEmpty ((!:))
import Data.Sequence (Seq)
import Geometry
import Graphics.GL
import Linear
import Linear.Affine
import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq

data Obj =
  Obj {objVertices :: !(Seq (V3 Double))
      ,objNormals :: !(Seq (V3 Double))
      ,objFaces :: !(Seq (V2 (V3 Int)))}
  deriving (Show)

instance Monoid Obj where
  mempty = Obj mempty mempty mempty
  Obj a b c `mappend` Obj x y z =
    Obj (a <> x)
        (b <> y)
        (c <> z)

parseLine :: Parser Obj
parseLine =
  vertex <|> normal <|> face <|>
  (mempty <$ skipWhile (not . isEndOfLine))
  where vertex =
          do string "v"
             skipSpace
             v <- v3
             return $!
               Obj (Seq.singleton v) mempty mempty
        normal =
          do string "vn"
             skipSpace
             v <- v3
             return $!
               Obj mempty (Seq.singleton v) mempty
        face =
          do string "f"
             skipSpace
             let v =
                   (,) <$> decimal <* char '/' <* decimal <* char '/' <*> decimal
             (v1,n1) <- v
             skipSpace
             (v2,n2) <- v
             skipSpace
             (v3,n3) <- v
             mv4 <-
               optional (do skipSpace
                            v)
             return $!
               Obj mempty
                   mempty
                   (Seq.singleton
                      (V2 (V3 v1 v2 v3)
                          (V3 n1 n2 n3)) <>
                    case mv4 of
                      Just (v4,n4) ->
                        Seq.singleton
                          (V2 (V3 v1 v3 v4)
                              (V3 n1 n3 n4))
                      Nothing -> mempty)
        v3 =
          do x <- double
             skipSpace
             y <- double
             skipSpace
             z <- double
             return $! V3 x y z

parseObj :: Parser Obj
parseObj = go mempty
  where go !acc =
          do !l <- parseLine
             acc' <- return $! acc <> l
             endOfLine *> go acc' <|> acc' <$ endOfInput
```

Running this with a 36MB obj file parses sucessfully, but

```
  21,342,866,200 bytes allocated in the heap
   1,263,590,520 bytes copied during GC
     290,617,624 bytes maximum residency (10 sample(s))
      56,958,112 bytes maximum slop
             547 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     41177 colls,     0 par    0.711s   0.708s     0.0000s    0.0008s
  Gen  1        10 colls,     0 par    0.241s   0.241s     0.0241s    0.1669s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    5.071s  (  5.077s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.952s  (  0.949s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.020s  (  0.020s elapsed)
  Total   time    6.055s  (  6.046s elapsed)

  %GC     time      15.7%  (15.7% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    4,208,709,362 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  84.3% of total user, 84.4% of total elapsed
```

While the productivity is good, 6 seconds to open an `.obj` file with 547MB total memory usage seems excessive. I've uploaded a heap profile [here](http://heap.ezyang.com/view/50abaafd809e47fd1e50b4f261b539099722c9ab). The `.prof` file is

```
    Fri Jun  5 22:36 2015 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       Deferred +RTS -p -RTS

    total time  =        5.17 secs   (5173 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 13,142,553,520 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE      MODULE                %time %alloc

parseLine.v3     WavefrontObj           69.8   69.5
parseLine.face.v WavefrontObj            8.4   13.7
parseLine.face   WavefrontObj            7.0    6.1
timeLog          Deferred                3.3    1.2
parseLine        WavefrontObj            2.8    1.7
parseLine.normal WavefrontObj            2.5    3.6
readTextDevice   Data.Text.Internal.IO   2.2    0.1
parseLine.vertex WavefrontObj            1.7    2.6
mappend          WavefrontObj            1.4    1.1


                                                                           individual     inherited
COST CENTRE              MODULE                          no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                     MAIN                             85           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main                    Deferred                        171           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
  timeLog                Deferred                        173           0    3.3    1.2   100.0  100.0
   parseObj              WavefrontObj                    178           0    0.0    0.0    94.4   98.7
    parseObj.go          WavefrontObj                    179     1080806    0.6    0.5    94.4   98.7
     parseLine           WavefrontObj                    181           0    2.8    1.7    93.8   98.2
      parseLine.v3       WavefrontObj                    190           0   69.7   69.5    70.8   70.3
       mappend           WavefrontObj                    191      667027    1.0    0.8     1.0    0.8
      parseLine.face     WavefrontObj                    187           0    7.0    6.1    16.9   21.3
       parseLine.face.v  WavefrontObj                    195           0    8.4   13.7     9.7   15.2
        parseLine.normal WavefrontObj                    196           0    0.9    1.3     1.2    1.5
         mappend         WavefrontObj                    197      127769    0.3    0.3     0.3    0.3
       parseLine.normal  WavefrontObj                    193           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
       mappend           WavefrontObj                    188      286011    0.1    0.0     0.1    0.0
      parseLine.normal   WavefrontObj                    185           0    1.5    2.3     1.6    2.3
       parseLine.v3      WavefrontObj                    192           0    0.1    0.0     0.1    0.0
      parseLine.vertex   WavefrontObj                    183           0    1.7    2.6     1.7    2.6
   readTextDevice        Data.Text.Internal.IO           174       18260    2.2    0.1     2.2    0.1
 CAF                     Deferred                        169           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                   Deferred                        170           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   timeLog               Deferred                        172           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     WavefrontObj                    166           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  parseLine              WavefrontObj                    180           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   parseLine.v3          WavefrontObj                    189           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   parseLine.face        WavefrontObj                    186           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    parseLine.face.v     WavefrontObj                    194           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   parseLine.normal      WavefrontObj                    184           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   parseLine.vertex      WavefrontObj                    182           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  mempty                 WavefrontObj                    176           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  parseObj               WavefrontObj                    175           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   parseObj.go           WavefrontObj                    177           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     Data.Attoparsec.Text.Internal   153           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     Data.Scientific                 152           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     Data.Text.Array                 150           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     Data.Text.Internal              148           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.Err                         135           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.IO.Handle.FD                132           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.IO.Handle.Internals         131           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.Conc.Signal                 125           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.IO.Encoding                 121           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.IO.FD                       120           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.Conc.Sync                   108           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv           106           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.Integer.Type                 92           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

I have a guess that seeing as my hotspot is the `v3` parser, this might just be something to do with using the `double` parser.

Comment: "36M obj file" is not that helpful (are the coordinates like `1` or `0.0123456789`); roughly how many vertices, normals and faces do you have?

Comment: @ReidBarton: 177277 vertices, 489750 normals, 127769 faces. All vertex coordinates/normals are specified as doubles - -45.440701 to pick a random example. Everything seems to have that precision.

Comment: So just accounting for the size of the data structure you want to build (10 words for a `V3 Double`, 23 words for a `V2 (V3 Int)`, ~3 words per element of a `Seq`), we're at around 96-122 MB (depending on how many of your faces are square), plus 76 MB for the input (since you're using Text), and so we've accounted for over half the max residency already. A heap profile by closure description (`-hd`) might help you see if there's any unevaluated stuff lying around as well.

Comment: One approach that can work in some situations is to refrain from parsing the whole file as one value. This will probably only help if you have the means to use the lines incrementally, and if you have a way to deal with a parse failure should it occur after you've already sent some lines on for further processing/action. I'm not familiar with your particular problem domain.

Comment: This will likely have negligible effects, but what happens if you change `vertex <|> normal` into `(char 'v' *> (vertex <|> normal))` and the first lines of `vertex` and `normal` into `char ' '` and `char 'n'` respectively? It will avoid a small amout of backtraking when encountering a "vn".

Comment: does `V3` have strict fields? It might also help to just use attoparsec for `parseLine` so you can stream input lines, and don't need to retain the whole file in memory for attoparsec's backtracking. And I'm confused by your heap profile which mentions an `mappend` called in `parseLine.v3`

Comment: @ReidBarton Something seems suspect there, because the original file *in ASCII* contains exactly the same information, yet that's 36mb! So somehow a more efficient binary encoding is triple the size... I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: @ReidBarton Oh, I got it. We were interpreting as megabits, not megabytes. By my calculations http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=177277+*+10+%2B+489750+*+10+%2B+127769+*+23+bytes+in+megabytes I should be use 9MB of space, so something is definitely going wrong!

Comment: @jberryman I'm using this V3 definition: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.18.1.1/docs/Linear-V3.html. It's strict. I tried defining one specialised to Double and using {-# UNPACK #-} but it makes barely a dent.

Comment: What more efficient binary encoding? :) I'm counting in words (= 8 bytes), no bits anywhere. `Double#` is one word = 8 bytes which is not very much more efficient than ASCII `"-45.440701 "` = 11 bytes. Add in one `D#` constructor and one `V3` pointer field per `Double#` and a little more for the `Seq` structure and then you're in the ballpark of triple the input file size. Using a `data D3 = D3 !Double !Double !Double` should certainly help a lot if your goal is to reduce space usage...

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is in the definition of `Obj`:

```
data Obj =
  Obj {objVertices :: !(Seq (V3 Double))
      ,objNormals :: !(Seq (V3 Double))
      ,objFaces :: !(Seq (V2 (V3 Int)))}
  deriving (Show)
```

Within your parser you only ever use one of the three fields, but you evaluate to WHNF and allocate space for an empty sequence for each `Obj`  This will almost triple the space of an `Obj` in memory compared to its size in a flat text file.  You also always have a `Seq.singleton` instance (also evaluated to WHNF) for every element.  You are paying a price in time and memory for this.

You may say, "But all my time is spent in `v3`," and you would be correct.  However all that time is spent in the allocation of memory, which (I think?) includes the cost of running the garbage collector. Statistically you are most likely to catch GC cycles where you do the most allocation.

**My suggestions:**

- See what happens if you take the strictness out of `Obj` it may not work as a complete solution, but it will show you if that is the problem for the cost of deleting three `!`.  If I'm wrong you've lost very little.
- Convert `Obj` to a sum type instead of a product type.
- Use a more conventional parser.  Parsec is awesome when it comes to clean express ability and the complexity of the grammars it can handle, but is just not in the same class perfromance-wise as other more limited parsing techniques.

**Possible Sum Type for `Obj`**:

```
data Obj =
    Empty 
  | Vertex (V3 Double)
  | Normal (V3 Double)
  | Face   (V2 (V3 Int))
  | Obj {objVertices :: !(Seq (V3 Double))
        ,objNormals  :: !(Seq (V3 Double))
        ,objFaces    :: !(Seq (V2 (V3 Int)))}

Instance Monoid Obj where
  mempty = Empty
  mappend Empty x = x
  mappend x Empty = x
  mappend (Face v) (obj@Obj{objFaces = vs}) = obj{objFaces = v<|vs}
  mappend (obj@Obj{objFaces = vs}) (Face v) = obj{objFaces = vs |> v}
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, you could be on to something here! I'll try and get a new benchmark done with this approach, and will see what the difference is.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the answer to line based formats parsing is to use `BS.lines` and `BS.words` from `Data.ByteString.Char8`. It isn't really pretty, but no parser combinator approach while be quite as fast or memory efficient. Something like :

```
parseLine :: BS.ByteString -> [Either Xxx Obj]
parseLine = map prs . BS.lines

prs :: BS.ByteString -> Either Xxx Obj
prs l = case BS.words l of
         ["v", x, y, z] -> do
             v <- V3 <$> parseDouble x <*> parseDouble y <*> parseDouble z
             return $ Obj (Seq.singleton v) mempty mempty
         ...
         _ -> Left "blah"
```

That's for performance. For memory usage you'll probably want to use primitive vectors, and unpacked data types generally. It doesn't seem to be the case in your example, but you also need to check how the libraries you are using implement their data types. For example `UTCTime` from the `time` package uses a *lot* of memory.

Final tip: I usually parameter my data types with the type of "string" that they use. My parser functions return `Foo ByteString`, and I convert to `Foo Text` the subset that I will keep in memory and manipulate.

Comment: This could work, and I need to try and benchmark it. For now, I've dropped attoparsec entirely and just built a little State parser using bytestring-lexing, which parses in 500ms - vastly better than anything I could achieve with attoparsec. I'll see if the line based one is in the same ballpark, but I think the Double parser may be much slower.